# Pythonic way to parse preflib Orders with Ties files

Tags: python, string, parsing

I'm working with data from preflib.org, especially with the "Orders with Ties" format. The format looks (somewhat) like this:

```
1,2,{3,4,5},6
2,{3,6,4},1,5
{2,3},{4,6},{1,5}
...
```

I need to parse every line of these files into a list of tuples, where every tuple contains one "equivalence class" of choices. In this example:

```
1,2,{3,4,5},6 -> [(1,), (2,), (3,4,5), (6,)]
2,{3,6,4},1,5 -> [(2,), (3,6,4), (1), (5,)]
{2,3},{4,6},{1,5} -> [(2,3), (4,6), (1,5)]
```

Currently this is solved with ugly string manipulations etc. and I am pretty sure there is something more pythonic to solve this (preferably with builtins only).

EDIT: What I do currently (very hacky and ugly ...):

```
s = "1,2,{3,4,5},6"
classes = []
equiv_cls = None
for token in s.split(","):
    if token.startswith("{"):
        equiv_cls = [token[1:]]
    elif token.endswith("}"):
        equiv_cls.append(token[:-1])
        classes.append(tuple(equiv_cls))
        equiv_cls = None
    elif equiv_cls is not None:
        equiv_cls.append(token)
    else:
        classes.append(tuple(token))
```

Comment: so what do you do currently?

Comment: I'm curious why you want a list of tuples.  A list of sets would be more accurate, no?

Comment: I need these objects to be hashable, the equivalence classes are keys in dicts, sets are afaik not hashable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) with some `str.replace` calls:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> s = '1,2,{3,4,5},6'
>>> [x if isinstance(x, tuple) else (x,) for x 
                         in literal_eval(s.replace('{', '(').replace('}', ')'))]
[(1,), (2,), (3, 4, 5), (6,)]
```

As @Martijn Pieters suggested you can replace the two `str.replace` calls with a single `str.translate` call:

```
>>> from string import maketrans
>>> table = maketrans('{}', '()')
>>> [x if isinstance(x, tuple) else (x,) for x in literal_eval(s.translate(table))]
[(1,), (2,), (3, 4, 5), (6,)]
```

In Python 3 you won't need any `str.replace` or `str.translate` calls calls, it fails in Python 2.7 and here is the [related bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue13536):

```
>>> [tuple(x) if isinstance(x, set) else (x,) for x in literal_eval(s)]
[(1,), (2,), (3, 4, 5), (6,)]
```

Comment: Does not create singleton-tuples for the solo elements?

Comment: @selllikesybok OP's code had no singleton tuples in their original question.

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary sorry I did not clarify that correctly, edited that in now. I need the list to be a list of tuples.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very crude and silly approach but worth a look

```
x = "2,{3,6,4},1,5"

y = x.replace("{",'(')
y = y.replace("}",')')
y = '['+y+']'
j = []
y = eval(y)
for i in y:
    typ = str(type(i))
    if(typ == "<class 'int'>"):
        j.append((i,))
    else:
        j.append(i)

print (j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another regex approach:

```
def parse_orders_with_ties(s):
    s2 = re.sub(r"{([\d,]+)}|(\d+)", r"(\g<0>,)", s)
    s2 = re.sub(r"[{}]", "", s2)
    v = ast.literal_eval("[" + s2 + "]")
    return v
```

Answer (score 0):

For converting this data into the required list string manipulation is necessary. After basic manipulation is done the data can be converted to list using only builtins.

The following function can be a possible solution:

```
def convert(str_data):
    b = str_data.split(',')
    list_data = []
    flag = 0
    for each_elem in b:
        if flag == 0 :
            next_str = ''
        if '{' in each_elem :
            next_str += each_elem.split('{')[1] + ','
            flag = 1
        elif flag == 1 and '}' not in each_elem :
            next_str += each_elem + ','
        elif flag == 1 and '}' in each_elem:
            next_str += each_elem.split('}')[0]
            list_data.append(next_str)
            flag = 0
        else:
            list_data.append(each_elem)
    return list_data
```

> > > > z = convert("{2,3},{4,6},{1,5}")
> > > >
> > > > z
> > > >
> > > > ['2,3', '4,6', '1,5']